# error: This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used

Tags: flutter, dart, void, dart-null-safety, snackbar

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Utils{
  static final messengerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();

  static showSnackBar(String? text){
    if (text == null) return;

    final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(text), backgroundColor: Colors.red,);

    messengerKey.currentState!.removeCurrentSnackBar().showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned before `void Funtion()` can't be assigned to anything.
So what happens here is `messengerKey.currentState!.removeCurrentSnackBar()` returns `void`, that's why you can't use anything after that.
But if you use `..` you return the object function was called on, therefore `messengerKey.currentState!..removeCurrentSnackBar()..showSnackBar(snackBar);` is a valid expression

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Utils{ 
   

static showSnackBar(GlobalKey messengerKey,String? text){ if (text == null) return;

final snackBar = SnackBar(content: Text(text), backgroundColor: Colors.red,);

messengerKey.currentState!.removeCurrentSnackBar().showSnackBar(snackBar);
} }
```

try this pass global key in function,seems like due to not initializing  key you are getting issue

Answer (score 0):

`showSnackBar` is a function of `currentState` but you try to apply it to another function. Split it up like

```
messengerKey.currentState!.removeCurrentSnackBar();
messengerKey.currentState!.showSnackBar(snackBar);
```

or alternatively write it like this:

```
messengerKey.currentState!..removeCurrentSnackBar()..showSnackBar(snackBar);
```